# Как перевести объект с типа str в int

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть список с числами и мне нужно два объекта из списка добавить как числа.
у меня не получается перевести объект из типа str в int.
например

```
a=1289
b=list(str(a))
c=b[0]+b[1]
print(c)
```

вывод:12
нужный результат:3
у меня не получается перевести объект с типа str в int

Comment: ну тоесть `str(a)` мы сделали. А что мешает сделать `c=int(b[0])+int(b[1])`?

Comment: Вы можете задачу комплексно описать, что является конечной целью задачи? Ну и основное условие тоже озвучьте, если не сложно.

Comment: Вывод не 12, а '12'. Это разные вещи. А каким образом должно получиться 13?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ ,просто, у меня в онлайн версии питона выдавало ошибку вот я пришел спросить и в вопросе опечатка там 3 должно быть а не 13.

Answer (score 1):

Строго говоря операция создания списка тут вообще лишняя, в Python строка итерируемый объект и к символам строки можно обращаться как к элементам списка. Тоесть достаточно было:

```
b=str(a)
```

Ну и весь Ваш код выглядел бы так:

```
a = 1289
b = str(a)
c = int(b[0]) + int(b[1])  # sum(map(int, b[:2])) или sum([int(_) for _ in b[:2]])
print(c)

# 3
```